# MapMaker Design Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, guava

I was impressed by google's [MapMaker](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#UKMs0lhE9bg/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.java&q=MapMaker%20package%3ahttp://guava-libraries%5C.googlecode%5C.com&exact_package=http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) design.I would like to know what is the name of the pattern that is used here ?

( What i think is it's somewhat like decorator pattern but in which we don't have to wrap the object in other object to extend the functionality,but I can't figure out exactly what sort of pattern it is. )

**MapMaker Object Creation:-**

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
      .concurrencyLevel(32)
      .softKeys()
      .weakValues()
      .expiration(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      .makeComputingMap(
          new Function<Key, Graph>() {
            public Graph apply(Key key) {
              return createExpensiveGraph(key);
            }
          });
```

Comment: To learn about design patterns by real world examples, you may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195) useful.

Comment: You'll never miss an opportunity to point that one out, eh? :-) Granted: it *is* one of the best java answers on this site...

Comment: @BaluC:That is surely a great answer,+1 from me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with a [Fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) api

Answer (score 5):

Builder and/or Fluent Interface

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 1):

I think it's kind of Builder.